# How do we know exact name of features and available features in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-rest

```
mn create-app my-project --features mongo-reactive,security-jwt
```

I found this on the official website of Micronaut. I would like to know how do I know the exact name of features and features supported by Micronaut.

Answer (score 3):

**Micronaut 1.x**

At first you need to know the profile name. Where profile is like a project template consisting of a *skeleton* project structure with default configuration, build dependencies and other assets, along with a set of commands for generating application-appropriate artifacts.

You can list profiles using command:

```
mn list-profiles
```

Than you can list all possible Micronaut features for that profile using this command:

```
mn profile-info service
```

Result list contains feature names with their short description. Features denoted by `(+)` are included by default. In the example above features for the `service` profile are listed.

Or you can list all base features which are available in all profiles:

```
mn profile-info base
```

Here is a [detail documentation for that](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.3.0/guide/#profiles).

**Micronaut 2.x**

As [James Kleeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264846/james-kleeh) noted, there are no more profiles in Micronaut CLI version 2.x.

Features can be listed directly by:

```
mn create-app --list-features
```

Here is a [detail documentation for that](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-starter/latest/guide/#commands).

Comment: Note that the CLI for 2.0 has no notion of profiles. The equivalent is `mn create-app --list-features`